# gcloud throws a lot of info/warn "scanned from multiple locations" when running standard Java appengine app on local machine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Since yesterday, when running my standard Java AppEngine app on local development machine, I got a lot of messages like this for different classes:

```
    [INFO] GCLOUD: 2018-11-10 09:29:59.763:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp1335050193-20: javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper scanned from multiple locations: 
    jar:file:///D:/Temp/endpoints-v2-backend/target/echo-j8-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar!/javax/jdo/spi/JDOImplHelper.class, 
    jar:file:///D:/Temp/endpoints-v2-backend/target/echo-j8-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/endpoints-management-control-appengine-all-1.0.10.jar!/javax/jdo/spi/JDOImplHelper.class
```

The problem can be reproduced with sample app from this https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java

A day before that I updated to the latest version of Google's Cloud SDK, so I'm not sure if the problem was there all the times and the latest version of Cloud SDK just simply start printing it out, or some recent update in either the SDK or the endpoints-framework caused the problem.

Anyway, despite those numerous info/warn messages, the app seems to run normally on my dev machine.

Do you know what happened? Can I ignore those messages and is it safe to deploy the build to production environment?

Comment: Updated Google Cloud SDK, getting the same warning

Comment: These info/warning messages should not cause your application to break. However, this does indicate that something is going on. I've created a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues/174

Comment: I am also getting similar warnings. Gcloud version was 227.0.0 when I noticed these warnings, and upgrading to 228.0.0 didn't help. Added a comment to the issue opened above.